# In Oracle SQL can I catch an error in TO_NUMBER and replace it with a default value?

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(my_number_or_something))
FROM my_table
```

The problem is that `my_number_or_something` is sometimes not a number, but text (maybe "n/a" or something).  Is there a simple way in SQL (specifically, Oracle's implementation) to catch the invalid rows and replace them with zero, or null, or some other value such that the `TO_NUMBER` function doesn't cause the query to fail?